# How can I select a random object from a class?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of 100+ objects, and I'd like to select 5 random objects and store them into variables, but I am not sure how to do that. What to do?
This is a simplified version of my code:

```
class playableCharacters:
    def __init__(self, name, power)

        self.name = name
        self.power = power

Aatrox = playableCharacters("Aatrox", 9)

Ahri = playableCharacters("Ahri", 3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a static list, and push the object in that list on `__init__`, then you can get 5 randomized int and they can be used as an index to that static list.

**Like this:**

```
import random

class playableCharacters:
    instances = []

    def __init__(self, name, power):
        self.name = name
        self.power = power
        __class__.instances.append(self)

Aatrox = playableCharacters("Aatrox", 9)
Ahri = playableCharacters("Ahri", 3)
# 100 more instances declaration.

randIndex = random.randrange(len(playableCharacters.instances))
randPlayerCharacter = playableCharacters.instances[randIndex]

print(randPlayerCharacter.name)
```

Like this, you can get 4 more randomized instances.

Comment: What if he wanted more than 5? You should automate the process of getting n number of random objects.

Comment: Surprising that we came up with almost the same solution independently. But I think you'll not be able to access `instances` from inside `__init__` and hence this code may not work.

Comment: He only wants 5 as of now.

Comment: @najeem why not?

Comment: Because i tried that first and got a `NameError`. Then realised that `instances` is not in `__init__`'s scope.

Comment: Does it matter? I see now that you've modified your code :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have some trouble getting the other random characters, every time I try it prints only one random character, how do I get it to print more than one? :/

Comment: @RadRazvan, Exactly, This code will only generate one random character, 4, on the other hand, I left for you to generate. So, that you can learn something.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve it with a class list

```
class playableCharacters:
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, name, power):

        self.name = name
        self.power = power
        __class__.instances.append(self)

a = playableCharacters("a", 9)
b = playableCharacters("b", 3)
c = playableCharacters("c", 9)
d = playableCharacters("d", 3)
# and so on.....
```

Now, you can get a set of 5 random object instances like

```
import random
random5 = random.choices(playableCharacters.instances, k=5)
```

I am not sure if this is the most optimal way if you have thousands of instances of the same class.

Comment: The print `name` was just to show it works. You could as well assign the random choice to a variable and access all properties.

Answer (score 1):

How about you use `random.choices(object_list, k=n)` where n = number of random items:

```
import random

class playableCharacters:
    def __init__(self, name, power):
        self.name = name
        self.power = power

    # Displays name when printed
    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.name)

# 5 Objects created
Aatrox = playableCharacters("Aatrox", 9)

Ahri = playableCharacters("Ahri", 3)

Test = playableCharacters("Test", 5)

Test2 = playableCharacters("Test2", 1)

Test3 = playableCharacters("Test3", 5)

# You could automate this, but for now here is a list of objects
myCharacters = [Aatrox, Ahri, Test, Test2, Test3]

# K=5 gives a list of 5 random
randomObjects = random.choices(myCharacters, k=5)
print(randomObjects)
```

EDIT:
Here is an automated version. Use a dictionary to represent the name and power key-value pairs:

```
import random

class playableCharacters:
    def __init__(self, name, power):
        self.name = name
        self.power = power

    # Displays name when printed
    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.name)

objects_to_be_created = {'Aatrox':9,'Ahri':3,'Test':5,'Test2':1,'Test3':5}

myCharacters = []

# Automatation
for o in objects_to_be_created:
    x = playableCharacters(o, objects_to_be_created[o])
    myCharacters.append(x)

# K=5 gives a list of 5 random
randomObjects = random.choices(myCharacters, k=5)
print(randomObjects)
```

Comment: Like OP said, there can be 100+ instances. How can that assignment thing be automated? Any pointer to this?

Comment: Assuming your objects are instantiated via a loop, you can add them to the myCharacters list every time they are created.